# Uploading multi images to server

Tags: php

I am working on the following code. Why am I not able to upload all images stored in the files? The code only upload `one` image into the server.

HTML

```
        <form id="uploader" action="#" method="post">
            Package Name
            <input type="text" name="rental_id_box" id="rental_id_box"/>
            <br /> Package Images
            <input id="selected_imgs" name="selected_imgs" type="file" multiple>
        </form>
```

JS:

```
    $("#btn-upload").on("click", function() {

      var fd = new FormData($('form')[0]);
    //fd.append( 'file', input.files[0] );
      var request = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "upload.php",
        data: fd,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        beforeSend: function() {
        console.log(fd);
        }
      });

      request.done(function(data) {
          $("#view").html(data)
      });

      request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
        console.log("Request failed: " + textStatus);
      });
    });
```

and PHP

```
<?php
$title = $_POST['rental_id_box'];
foreach($_FILES as $index => $file)
    {
        $fileName     = $file['name'];
        $fileTempName = $file['tmp_name'];

        if(!empty($file['error'][$index]))
        {
            return false;
        }
        if(!empty($fileTempName) && is_uploaded_file($fileTempName))
        {
            move_uploaded_file($fileTempName, "uploads/". $fileName);
            echo '<p>Click <strong><a href="uploads/' . $fileName . '" target="_blank">' . $fileName . '</a></strong> to download it.</p>';
        }
    }
```

Comment: `name="selected_imgs"` => `name="selected_imgs[]"`

Comment: Sorry can you please let me know what do does this means?

Comment: Add the form attribute  enctype='multipart/form-data'

Comment: Thanks jeff, but now I am getting this error `Warning: is_uploaded_file() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in C:\wamp64\www\Galley\upload.php on line 12`

Comment: This post does not contain a [mcve], and the answers below do not seem to have come to a satisfactory conclusion. Although there is an accepted answer, it is not of high quality, and there is a stream of error reports in a conversation under it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
...&& is_uploaded_file($_FILES['name']['tmp_name'])
```

Comment: Thanks Danes but I am getting this error now ` Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\wamp64\www\Galley\upload.php on line 13`

Comment: in place of name please put the value that you send it using form.

Comment: Ok I am confused! where exactly?

Comment: ...&& is_uploaded_file($_FILES['selected_imgs']['tmp_name'])

Comment: This is the errro now ` Warning: is_uploaded_file() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in D:\wamp64\www\Galley\upload.php on line 13`

Comment: Please add additional info/explanation to this answer. As it is, this answer is considered as "Low Quality Post" and candidate for deletion"

Answer (score 0):

```
if(count($_FILES['selected_imgs']['name']) > 0){
for($i=0; $i<count($_FILES['selected_imgs']['name']); $i++) {
    $tmpFilePath = $_FILES['selected_imgs']['tmp_name'][$i];
    print_r($tmpFilePath);
    if(($tmpFilePath != "")&&(is_uploaded_file($tmpFilePath))){            
        $filePath = "upload/" . date('d-m-Y-H-i-s').'-'.$_FILES['selected_imgs']['name'][0];
        move_uploaded_file($tmpFilePath, $filePath);
      }
}
```

}